# Tebex create Payment

Tags: error-handling, payment

I don't know what this error code is and what I should do:
**Please enter the 'Login with Discord so that we can identify you' Variable for the prime_marry Package.**

```
await axios({
  method: 'POST',
       url: `https://plugin.tebex.io/payments`,
           headers: {
                    'X-Tebex-Secret' : "SECRET_KEY"
           },
           data: {
               note: "Booster Script",
               packages: [
                 {
                    id: ScriptData["tbxId"]
                 }
               ],
               price: 0,
               ign: cfxNames[interaction.user.id]
           }
}).catch(e => { console.log('tebex error\n'); console.log(e) });
```

Since there are no entries I have not tried much